# detecting ParseObject in Custom List View

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, parse-platform

In each row, I have a button and a textView. When the Button is clicked, It successfully sets the textView to a new value in that row. However, When I call `ParseQuery()` in `GetView();` and try to do `object.put("objectName", num)` The only value that is populated to my Parse-Server is the last row.  **My `SetTag();` and `GetTag();` and `ViewHolder class` is correct** When I click the button, I believe android studio is unsure of which row's TextView to populate so it just automatically populates the last row's TextView.

**Custom ListView Adapter Class**

```
public class CustomFeedListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

String likesString;
int position;

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> feed;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

ParseObject parseObFeed;

public CustomFeedListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    this.feed = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feed.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return feed.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

     position = i;

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_list_row, viewGroup, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.feedProfilePic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedProfilePic);
        holder.feedUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUsernameId);
        holder.feedNumOfLikes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedNumofLikes);
        holder.feedUpVoteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUpVoteButton);


        view.setTag(holder);

        HashMap<String, String> mFeed = new HashMap<>();

        mFeed = feed.get(i);


        holder.feedNumOfLikes.setText(mFeed.get("likes"));
        likesString = mFeed.get("likes");
        holder.mLikes = Integer.valueOf(likesString);

        position = i;

    }
    else{
        position = i;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.feedUpVoteButton.setTag(position); 

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("FeedItem");
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if(e == null){


                    for (final ParseObject object : objects) {

                        holder.feedUpVoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ParseObject[] mParseObject = new  ParseObject[feed.size()];

                                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();

                                mParseObject[pos] = object;

                                holder.likes[pos] = holder.mLikes;

                                mParseObject[pos].put("likes", holder.likes[pos]);

                                mParseObject[pos].saveInBackground();
                                holder.feedNumOfLikes.setText(String.valueOf(holder.likes[pos]
                                ));                                

                            }
                        });

                    }


            }

        }
    });


    return view;
}




class ViewHolder {
    ImageView feedProfilePic;
    TextView feedUsername;
    TextView feedNumOfLikes;
    TextView feedFeedItem;
    TextView feedDate;
    TextView feedNumofReplies;
    Button feedUpVoteButton;
    Button feedDownVoteButton;
    Button feedCommentButton;
    ListView feedListView;
    int likes[] = new int[feed.size()];
    int mLikes;
 }


}
```

Comment: The solution is simpler than I thought. You need to create a new ParseObject, then `parseObFeed = objects.get(pos);` in the query.